# serve a zip file in tornado.web

Tags: python, zip, download, tornado

I'm new to tornado and I need to serve a zip file (made by python).

So i added this code lines to my script, found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-tornado/SqkMewV89wk):

```
        zipname="clients_counter.zip"
        zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zipname, "w")
        for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk("tozip"):
            zf.write(dirname)
            for filename in files:
                zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
        zf.close()
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/zip')
        self.write(zipname.getvalue())
        self.finish()
```

This just gives me a white page as a result, it doessn't start the download.  Does anyone a better advice to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send the zipfile to browser on the fly (without saving to the local filesystem), try this:

```
from io import BytesIO
zipname="clients_counter.zip"
f=BytesIO()
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(f, "w")
    for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk("tozip"):
        zf.write(dirname)
        for filename in files:
            zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
zf.close()
self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/zip')
self.set_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=%s" % zipname)
self.write(f.getvalue())
f.close()
self.finish()
```

BytesIO object is where the zipfile goes, and the zipname is just a name sent to client's browser.

Comment: Better use `with zipfile.ZipFile(f, "w") as zf:` to make sure `close` is always called

Answer (score 0):

I've read a little bit around and this is what I found out: I've built up the directory static for tornado, i've changed the python code to store the zip file inside the static folder:

```
zipname="C:/whatever/static/clients_counter.zip"
        zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zipname, "w")
        for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk("tozip"):
            zf.write(dirname)
            for filename in files:
                zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
        zf.close()
        self.write("""<a href="/static/clients_counter.zip"> Download Zip of client counter files</a>""")
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()

settings = {
"static_path" : os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static")
}  # This indicates the directory for static files to the server: 
   # it has to be a directory called static inside the project directory
```

Much easier than building a new directory or using other more difficult hacks. If this can help anyone, i'm glad.